# How to locate element using any locator method in selenium webdriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is my code but unable to locate element using any locator method in selenium webdriver with Ruby

```
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td width="43%" class="titles">User Id</td>
        <td width="57%"><input type="text" name="userId" size="12" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="titles">Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" size="12" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center" size="12"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried this ruby code to locate element,but it's not working

```
driver.find_element(:xpath,"//input[@name='userId']").send_keys("value")
driver.find_element(:xpath,"//input[@name='password']").send_keys("value")
```

Also tried this

```
driver.find_element(:name,"userId").send_keys("value")
driver.find_element(:name,password").send_keys("value")
```

Comment: Please show an example of your selenium webdriver ruby code & any errors you may be receiving.

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='userId']"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

Include the implicit wait before your coding. Write the following code

```
 driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait=20
 driver.find_element(:name,"userId").send_keys("username")
 driver.find_element(:name,"password").send_keys("password")
```